# Are query-dependent ranking algortihms for web search doomed to be impractical?

Tags: graph-algorithms

Algorithms like HITS and SALSA are query dependent, and I've been given the impression that this makes them able to retrieve more accurate results. However, the query-dependent nature of these algorithms makes them unusable for practical implementation. For example, I have read that HITS is impractically slow.

Are query dependent methods doomed to fail the practicality test? I've seen some papers that have tried to speed up the computations involved. Is adoption of query-dependent methods, or some hybrid, something we could see in future?

Comment: How is this a question on **theoretical** computer science?